# Создание зависимого объекта rails on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В данный момент у меня функционирует создание зависимого объекта из объекта-родителя:
Функция создания Job:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @job = @article.jobs.create(job_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
```

Job привязан к Article:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

И в данный момент у меня создается Job прямиком из артикля:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @article, @article.jobs.build ]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :Job %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Мне необходимо создать этот объект из списка артиклей на подобие этого, где идет не наследование из родителя, а выбор этого самого родителя (это по форме похоже, но на деле не работает):

```
<%= form_with scope: :job do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select name="article_id" id="article_id">
    <%= options_from_collection_for_select(Article.all, :id, :title) %>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Я так понимаю что мне необходимо сам метод создания в контроллере изменить и саму функцию, а вот как, даже не догадываюсь.

Лог создания через стандартную форму:

```
Started POST "/articles/7/jobs" for ::1 at 2019-11-09 11:11:10 +0300
Processing by JobsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"51pyqQ1vpzbQwlqHcEsL2uQ4TBHl654RSSUYL4IY4E
zoFXPtmtpa7OB0TlDX4+AkDlqaLpbjMbHDzq89IXgQNQ==", "job"=>{"text"=>"444"}, "commit
"=>"Создать Job", "article_id"=>"7"}
  Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id
" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ? app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:4:in `create'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ? app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:5:in `create'
  Job Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "jobs" ("text", "article_id", "created_at", "u
pdated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["text", "444"], ["article_
id", 7], ["created_at", "2019-11-09 08:11:10.499077"], ["updated_at", "2019-11-0
9 08:11:10.499077"]]
  ? app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:5:in `create'
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  ? app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:5:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles/7
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms | Allocations: 3656)


Started GET "/articles/7" for ::1 at 2019-11-09 11:11:10 +0300
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
  Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id
" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ? app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:11:in `show'
  Rendering articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Job Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."article_id" = $1
[["article_id", 7]]
  ? app/views/articles/show.html.erb:7
  Rendered collection of jobs/_job.html.erb [3 times] (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocat
ions: 343)
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.8ms |
Allocations: 2005)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 36.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 716
2)
```

Лог добавления через другую форму:

```
Started POST "/articles" for ::1 at 2019-11-09 11:15:19 +0300
Processing by ArticlesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"IFFYrRiqaM+GXP0K+mCclOPn03ptxUjXERFYIq1kSA
NADfC46RtU5+KME6m4CXgQqtS7scskoTArxBlDwonXag==", "job"=>{"text"=>"444"}, "articl
e_id"=>"7", "commit"=>"Сохранить Job"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 639)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: arti
cle):

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:31:in `article_params'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Routes:

```
                             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern
                                                      Controller#Action
                        welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)
                                                      welcome#index
                         article_jobs GET    /articles/:article_id/jobs(.:format
)                                                     jobs#index
                                      POST   /articles/:article_id/jobs(.:format
)                                                     jobs#create
                      new_article_job GET    /articles/:article_id/jobs/new(.:fo
rmat)                                                 jobs#new
                     edit_article_job GET    /articles/:article_id/jobs/:id/edit
(.:format)                                            jobs#edit
                          article_job GET    /articles/:article_id/jobs/:id(.:fo
rmat)                                                 jobs#show
                                      PATCH  /articles/:article_id/jobs/:id(.:fo
rmat)                                                 jobs#update
                                      PUT    /articles/:article_id/jobs/:id(.:fo
rmat)                                                 jobs#update
                                      DELETE /articles/:article_id/jobs/:id(.:fo
rmat)                                                 jobs#destroy
                             articles GET    /articles(.:format)
                                                      articles#index
                                      POST   /articles(.:format)
                                                      articles#create
                          new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)
                                                      articles#new
                         edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)
                                                      articles#edit
                              article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)
                                                      articles#show
                                      PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)
                                                      articles#update
                                      PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)
                                                      articles#update
                                      DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)
                                                      articles#destroy
                                 root GET    /
                                                      welcome#index
```

Comment: "не работает" - это не самое удачное слово. Лучше описать подробно, что происходит. В вашем вопросе очень не хватает логов сервера. Если в логах вы посмотрите в `parameters`, которые прилетают в контроллер от первой формы и от второй, вы сами скорее всего сможете написать всё верно.

Comment: добавил логи с сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте ещё раз внимательно про `form_with`. Самый простой способ работы с этим хелпером - через `model`, он автоматически определяет роут и правильно формирует параметры.

```
<%= form_with model: Job.new do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.collection_select(:article_id, Article.all, :id, :title) %>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Теперь `article_id` будет прилетать вместе с остальными параметрами, не забудьте добавить его в `job_params`. Какие бы параметры не прилетели из формы, будет использована только та часть, что лежит под ключом `job` (и этот ключ обязательно должен быть), а из неё будут взяты только значения ключей `text` и `article_id` - `{ job: { text: 'New text', article_id: 1 } }`

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:text, :article_id)
end
```

Экшн контроллера станет немного короче

```
def create
  @job = Job.create(job_params)
  redirect_to root_path # пусть будет редирект на главную страницу
end
```

Comment: Теперь выскакивает ошибка
      undefined method `jobs_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000007f0f2b0>:0x0000000007f1c2f8>
так как путь к работам содержится конкретно в артикле

Comment: Добавил routes в вопрос

Comment: @Александр добавьте `resources :jobs` в роуты

Comment: добавил, но на то, что артикля нет все еще ругается. ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: article):

Comment: @Александр как у вас выглядят `job_params`?

Comment: примерно так:
`def job_params
      params.require(:article_id)
      params.require(:job)
    end`

Comment: @Александр обновила ответ

Comment: Спасибо за терпение, я оказывается тугодум.

Comment: @Александр это нормально, когда что-то новое осваиваешь :) Главное, не останавливаться и учиться дальше